# NVDA reads entire content of the div when the div is on focus

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I have a situation where when a div is in focus, NVDA screen reader reads aria labels of all elements in the div.

Here is a code pen which I created to recreate this [Codepen - NVDA Screen reader](https://codepen.io/ravi139/pen/XWBzGjW)

There are three main div's in the HTML with class names - `first-row`, `separator` and `second-row`.

The div with class `second-row` has `tabindex="0"` to make it focusable. This is part of the requirement.
This div also contains 3 child div's with class - `header`, `content` and `footer` each one which has focusable elements with `aria-label`. The `footer` child div also has `tabindex="0"` which again is part of the requirement.

When the focus is on `second-row` or `footer`, the NVDA screen reader announces all contents of the div as shown below

1. `second-row` - Announced text below

[image]

2. `footer` - Announced text below

[image]

Our requirement was to not let the NVDA announce the div contents which adds to the confusion of the users.

**Questions**

1. Is this behavior correct ? Should the NVDA screen reader announce contents of a focusable div ?
2. I can try using `aria-hidden="true"` on these focusable div's but this also chains down to child elements, hence when the focus is on the child elements, the screen reader does not announce them. I can write focus-in and focus-out events to update the flag for aria-hidden, but is there any other workaround for this ?
3. Most of the times, when the focus reaches the first focusable element of a focusable div, NVDA does not announce anything. In the codepen example, the first input element of `footer` div. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Your requirement sounds wrong, and yes this is correct behaviour. a) Only interactive elements should receive focus. b) nesting interactive elements poses severe issues to usability and accessibility. Is there any interactivity on the mentioned elements, any event listeners?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you observe is absolutely correct. When an element is focused, the accessible content has to be read entirely by the screen reader.
It's the core of its functioning, tell the user what's under focus right now.

Your fundamental problem is that you have overlapping focusable elements.
**Focusable elements must never be overlapping**, or otherwise said, **a focusable element must never be inside another focusable element**.

Doing so creates several problems, such as what you observe with confusing content read twice. But also, when the focus is in the inner element, should keyboard events still be sent to both elements ? IN which order ?
Same question when clicking on it, which element(s) should take the focus and/or send events ? One, the other, or both, will arrange you in turn depending on the situation. There is no universal good and correct answer.
Knowing if being on the inside or outside element isn't always super clear either: is it the exact shape of the text or image, taking into account transparent parts or not, or is it the entire rectangular zone ? It depends on CSS background ? And so on.

IN short, it's too easy to make insanely confusing things for the users, so you must really avoid it.

The good news for you is that your tabindex=0 appear totally useless here. You should just remove them.

**An element must be focusable *if, and only if* interactions are possible with that element. If the element doesn't provide any interaction, then it shouldn't be focusable.**

Would you focus something which you can't do anything with ? At best it's a waste of energy/efficiency/time because you have to tab once more for nothing, and at worst it's only confusion for the user, who may not realize immediately that the focused element does nothing useful. What's more annoying than writing in the void ?

Here, your divs don't provide any interaction, so they shouldn't be focusable. Remove these totally useless tabindex=0 and voilà, problem solved.

Comment: I do understand that tabindex=0 in the example I provided is completely useless, but here it was for simplicity. In our actual use case, one of the div with tabindex=0 has multiple child div's (say X) whose count is based on user's configuration. We display an overlay hint panel when the focus is on the tabindex=0 div's. Along with that, we also  additional interaction using custom keyboard commands to move focus from these parent div's to the child X div's. I know it sounds complicated, but that's what the requirement was which I doubt can be changed now

Comment: What you describe is in fact the composite component pattern. The actual solution for that case is to set tabindex=0 on the particular child really having the focus inside the component, set tabindex=-1 on all other children, and switch tabindex from 0 to -1 and back as you are moving in the component. In any case, it never makes sense for the root div itself to be focusable.

Comment: @RaviSankarRao the important part in the described composite component pattern is that focus is _not_ moved by means of the tab key inside the component, but rather with arrow keys. You can read up [more on the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-6-1-managing-focus-within-components-using-a-roving-tabindex)